# Shell script on running a docker container

Tags: docker, shell, sh

I created a `Dockerfile` like below:

```
From alpine:latest

WORKDIR /
COPY ./init.sh .
CMD ["/bin/sh", "./init.sh"]
```

and a script file `init.sh` like below:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p mount_point
echo hello > ./mount_point/hello.txt
```

and I built an image using these:

```bash
docker build . -t test_build
```

and ran it as

```bash
docker container run --rm --name test_run -it test_build sh
```

where there are only two above files in the folder.

In the container, I can find the `init.sh` file with `x` (executable) as is in the host.

However, there is no folder `mount_point` which should be created by

```
CMD ["bin/sh", "./init.sh"]
```

Note that, when I run any of the below in the container, it successfully creates `mount_point` as I expected

```bash
sh init.sh
```

or

```bash
/bin/sh init.sh
```

and

```bash
sh -c ./init.sh
```

Could you tell me where I made mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
docker container run --rm --name test_run -it test_build sh
```

the `sh` at the end overrides the CMD definition in the image and the CMD isn't run.

To verify that your script works, your can change the script to something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello from the script!
mkdir -p mount_point
echo hello > ./mount_point/hello.txt
ls -al ./mount_point
```

Then run the image without the `sh` and you should see the 'Hello' message and the directory listing from the ./mount_point directory.

```
docker container run --rm --name test_run test_build
```